# on click modal is not opening locally

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to work with modal here.

Below is the code of my modal.

```
<div class="modal-wrapper modal-popup-signup">
        <div class="modal-close modal-popup-signup-close"></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h1>SIGN UP</h1> 
            <form action="" class="password-change">
                <h2>E-MAIL ID*</h2>
                <input type="text" class="text">
                <h2>PASSWORD*</h2>
                <input type="password" class="text">
                <h2>TITLE*</h2>
                <h2>FIRST NAME </h2>
                <input type="text" class="text">
                <h2>LAST NAME </h2>
                <input type="text" class="text">

                <input type="submit" class="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

On this `li` I have a anchor tag where i am opening the Modal.

```
  <ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
    <li><a href="#"class="modal-popup-signup-open">Signup</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Here's the JS for it.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.modal-popup-signup-open').click(function(){
            $('.modal-popup-signup').css("display", "block");
        });
  $('.modal-popup-signup-close').click(function(){
          $('.modal-popup-signup').css("display", "none");
        });
  });
```

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sLq6172/), It for some reason worked here but not working for me locally.

**EDIT !** : I am doing this only for small screen. So when I go to full window size I can see the pop-up. But why not for small screen? Provided I am using proper bootstrap modal.

Comment: You getting any error in console?

Comment: Okay, so here's the issue I think.

I am doing this thing only for small screens. 

And when I resize my window to full, the modal appears back.

Comment: but in ur fiddle link i cant see any pop up.

Comment: on click to Signup, Modal's form appears @KamleshArya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open pop-up:

```
$('.modal-popup-signup-open').click(function(){
            $('.modal-popup-signup').modal('show');
        });
```

To close:

```
$('.modal-popup-signup-close').click(function(){
          $('.modal-popup-signup').modal('hide');
        });
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6sLq6172/5/)

Comment: Please don't repeat the answer

Comment: dude..how come my answer is ur repeat...u dint even gave solution to hide the pop up

Comment: Hey. Question is about only opening, So your answer for opening is same as me.

Comment: Calm down guys, Thanks for the answer. 

But this isn't the actual issue. 
even with `display:block` It was working but was not visible when my window was of mobile size.

I am doing this thing only for small screens. 

And when I resize my window to full, the modal pops up

Comment: update your jquery/bootstrap and check for any console error

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$('.modal-popup-signup').css("display", "block");
```

Use following

```
$('.modal-popup-signup').modal('show');
```

for closing of modal use

```
$('.modal-popup-signup').modal('close');
```

and also use the `href="javascript:void(0)"` in anchor tag